# Paypal android integration : some locale currencies are not supported

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated `PayPal` to an android application using [PayPal android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK). Now I come to know that `PayPal` transactions are allowed in some of the countries only. If I use local currency for payment and `PayPal` does not support that locale then payment cannot be made.

Last paragraph of [PayPal mobile integration](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) says that `PayPal`'s SDK is for US developers only. Non-US developers should use [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) for time being.

I don't know if I should keep using SDK and figure out a workaround or should implement MPL.

Have anyone come across same situation?

Note : I am from India. But the account I use with `PayPal` is created from US.

Comment: Hi Akash 
When you use this paypal android sdk , is it working fine in india?

Comment: @Rank I am using PayPal as it does not serve my purpose. Btw PayPal does not support all countries, so you have to check it first. I don't remember for India as I did not proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it in the documentation below(Country & Currency Support for PayPal REST API Payments)
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/